# Why is gdb throwing internal errors and telling me that there is a bug?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm trying to debug a simple program but gdb is acting up. I get internal errors and then gdb saying that there's a bug. This happens when I try to stop the running program. After sending Keyboard Interrupt to go back to the debugger, I try to exit the whole debugger with `quit`. But when I do that, I get this (I also include what happens when I go through the questions):

```
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 1239] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
../../gdb/target.c:2149: internal-error: void target_mourn_inferior(ptid_t): Assertion `ptid == inferior_ptid' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) y

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

../../gdb/target.c:2149: internal-error: void target_mourn_inferior(ptid_t): Assertion `ptid == inferior_ptid' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) y
Abort trap: 6 (core dumped)
```

Can someone tell me what is going on, why it's happening, and how to fix it please?

Comment: Most likely from a bug in your program.  First try running it through valgrind.

Comment: Are you running on an ARM Mac? There's a candidate [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26861).

Comment: I am running Intel

Comment: What does `xcodebuild -version` print?

Comment: `Xcode 11.3.1
Build version 11C505`

Comment: @MatthewSchell: I think that is the latest supported on macOS Mojave (10.14.*). You could try Xcode 10 (or maybe earlier versions of 11) or you could create a minimal reproducible example and enter a new question asking for workarounds. Also, are you actually using gdb? Apple dropped it from its tools a while ago in favor of lldb. If you are using a gdb from some non-Apple source, it may not have the prerequisites it needs to operate properly. E.g., maybe there is some difference in the debug information formats that it does not work with.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that lldb just worked for me and didn't throw any errors so I'll stick with that instead. Plus there's not much of a difference between the 2 debuggers (I don't think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what is going on

GDB has already told you:

> ```
> This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
> <https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
> ```

If a program ever reports that it itself has a bug then it is always right.  Even if the behavior it thinks is buggy in fact is not, then the program is buggy to say otherwise.

In this particular case, GDB is reporting the failure of an assertion in its own code.  This is definitely an implementation bug, not a bug-reporting bug.

> why it's happening

It is likely triggered by something unusual about the program being debugged -- which may be buggy itself -- but that doesn't make it any less a GDB bug.

> and how to fix it please?

You are unlikely to be able to fix the gdb bug yourself, but it may be that there is a newer version to which you could upgrade, in which the bug has been fixed.

Comment: How do I upgrade gdb?

Comment: It depends in part on where you got your gdb, @MatthewSchell. Among the possible ways to upgrade would be (i) upgrading your XCode and its command-line tools, or (ii) installing Fink or MacPorts and getting the latest version from there, or (iii) downloading the latest source release of GDB and building it yourself.

Comment: I used `xcode-select` to install the command line tools, and I'm running macOS Mojave right now. I don't really feel like upgrading to Catalina or BigSur so I guess I'm out of luck because these tools are outdated right?

Comment: @MatthewSchell, there may be an Xcode update available for Mojave.  And even if not, you could use one of the other alternatives I mentioned to install a second gdb that (one hopes) does not have the same bug.

Comment: Re “If a program ever reports that it itself has a bug then it is always right”: There is another way for this message to occur, and that is if a program’s prerequisites are not met, such as running it on a system it was not designed for. OP may be trying to run some non-Apple version of gdb with files generated by Apple’s tools, and it may be incompatible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it is conceivable that gdb failed for the OP on account of input that was in some way bad or unexpected, but in that case it would constitute a bug that it instead self-diagnoses the problem as a program bug.  But in this case there is another layer, too: if a runtime assertion ever trips then that definitely signals a program bug, whether in the assertion's test itself or in the code that affects the result of that test.  That is the meaning and proper usage of assertions.

Comment: A bug is a deviation from specification. Unless a program is specified to be able to diagnose that certain prerequisites are not met, it is not a deviation to “misbehave” because those prerequisites are not met. (It is obviously impossible for a program to diagnose all of its prereqisites, since some of the prerequisites include that it be executed on a certain type of processor, that the processor function as it is specified, and so on.) In other words, intentional lack of input error checking is not necessarily a bug, even if it causes an incorrect message that the program has a bug.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the definition for "bug" that you assert supports your argument, but I reject that definition as too narrow.  Merriam-Webster, for instance, defines the word as "an unexpected defect, fault, flaw, or imperfection", and I, at least have expectations of software behavior that sometimes extend beyond specifications.  You may, in this sense, take my claim at issue as reflecting one such expectation.

Answer (score 0):

> what is going on

There is a bug in your version of GDB.

> why it's happening

GDB is a program. Programs have bugs. You managed to hit one of them. Perhaps [this one](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26861)?

> and how to fix it please?

If you are on MacOS, update above bug with the simplest program which demonstrates this behavior and *hope* that some GDB developer will fix that bug soon.